# How does Dr. Perrow know Grace is Traveler 0027?

Tags: plot-explanation, travelers

During the interrogation in *Travelers*, when Grace mocked Dr. Perrow (probably Vincent Ingram who had transferred his consciousness into Dr. Perrow), Dr. Perrow told Grace to "stop pretending, Traveler 0027".

How does Dr Perrow (even if she is Vincent Ingram) know Grace is 0027? 
Dr Perrow is a counselor, and Vincent came from a future earlier than Grace.

Answer (score 3):

In Season 2 Episode 11 "Simon", Marcy brings Simon to their base of operations. Later in the episode Simon will sit in front of Phillip's computer and do something. Phillip later explains that Simon was sent here from the future to create an encrypted messaging back channel over the existing communications channel or the internet.This back channel would be used by the future travelers to communicate with each other.

Phillip also explains that Vincent might have created another back channel on top of this so that he would be able to hack into each and every message that is being communicated.This also explains how Vincent knew about all the other teams that had arrived, whom he abducted for interrogation.

Assuming that Vincent Ingram had transferred his consciousness into Dr. Perrow before he started the interrogation, it was evident that he already knew about her as soon as she arrived from the future.